# How to retrieve elements in an enum type variable?

Tags: c, enums

When the code is compiled, it doesn't show the values inserted to the enum variable in structure

This code only shows the keyboard input 0 or 1

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define Max_CHARS_NAME 100

struct gps_point{
    double latitude;
    enum latitude_pole {North,South} pole;
    double longitude;
    enum longitude {East,West} dire;
    char location_name[Max_CHARS_NAME];
}g;

int main(){
    char arr[Max_CHARS_NAME];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter location\n");
    scanf("%s", &g.location_name);  
    strcpy(arr,g.location_name);

    printf("Enter latitude\n");
    scanf("%lf", &g.latitude);

    printf("Enter latitude pole North - 0, South - 1\n");
    scanf("%d",&g.pole);

    //g.latitude_pole = g.pole;

    printf("Enter longitude dire East - 0, West - 1\n");
    scanf("%d", &g.dire);

    printf("Enter longitude\n");
    scanf("%s", &g.longitude);

    printf("%s is situated at (Latitude : %s %lf , Longitude: %s %lf). \n",arr,g.pole,g.latitude,g.dire,g.longitude);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See the below example,

```
enum week{Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun}; 

int main() 
{ 
    enum week day; 
    day = Wed; 
    printf("%d",day); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Here we declare a variable day of type  week and assign one(numerical) value in the list to the variable using a "string" but it isn't possible to do the other way.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to

```
enum latitude_pole {
  North = 0,
  South = 1
} pole;
```

This defines the variable `pole` whose possible values are North(0) and South(1).

It is equivalent to writing

```
enum latitude_pole {
  North = 0,
  South
} pole;
```

because in case you initialize one member the next one will be `+1`(previous member).

In your code the missing of initialization will have it insert by default the value 0 for the first member and 1 for the second member.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give the enumeration constants any values, the compiler will do it silently.

The first one will always be given value `0`, and every following enumeration constant will get the value of previous constant + 1.

In your case `{North,South}`, `North` is guaranteed to be 0 and `South` guaranteed to be 1. The type of these enumeration constants is guaranteed to be 100% compatible with `int`.

Had you typed only some values explicitly, the rule where every constant getting the value of the previous + 1 is still applicable. So if you would do `{North,South,East=5,West}`, they would get the values `0, 1, 5, 6`.